# How to dynamically add xml data to spinner item by xmlpullparser

Tags: android, xml, parsing, spinner, xmlpullparser

I am trying to load spinner drop down item from a url by using xmlpullparser. I can parse the xml data but couldn't add them into spinner item dynamically.How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your XML data to an `ArrayList`, then use code like this:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                 (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourArrayList);

    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

If the underlying data changes, update the `ArrayList` and then call `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.